# Trying to create rich text link to source citation for inline citation with pandoc citeproc

Tags: pandoc, csl, pandoc-citeproc

Trying to create an output that would allow the `URL` part of a citation to appear as clickable rich text link to source file.

So far I have tried to create [a custom CSL file](https://gist.github.com/drakezint/d98dccdf73c7f2265c4d7f995fe54d0a) that would output as `(TITLE, DATE) ([SOURCE LINK](URL))` so that when I run it through pandoc it would turn into a rich text link when converted to DOCX, HTML, PDF, etc.

However, when I run the following command it populates it as escaped markdown that would not result as a rich link but just the raw text.

`pandoc input.md -o output.md --citeproc --csl chicago-custom.csl --bibliography references.bib`

I also tried to output as html but it creates the link for the URL, but not the "SOURCE LINK" part and looks like this: `/[SOURCE LINK]/(URL)` for markdown or `<a href="URL">URL</a>` with html output

Is there a different approach than custom CSL to do this?

Comment: How close to your desired output is the result of calling pandoc with the original CSL and `-M reference-links`?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't get me closer. I am wanting the citation to appear as an inline rich link to the source URL